# Upload Excel file and extract data - asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, excel-2007

I am wondering how do I extract data out of a 2007 excel file? I am using asp.net mvc 3. My plan is to have a upload section that you choose a file and hit upload. I have no clue after that what kind of format it will be or what I need to do to extract the values out.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have the spreadsheet uploaded and you save it to a file on the web server it is quite easy to use LINQ to select the rows from the spreadsheet. Check this out for more info.

http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: Super easy to use and has a nuget package as well.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to read excel spread sheets IMO is to use a DataAdapter and an OleDB connection as shown in this [code project sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx). The good thing about this is it does not have any dependencies on COM or the MS office libraries.

Answer (score 3):

For reading Excel files, I learned to love Koogra. It's an open source library that reads both xls and xlsx files, and is very easy to use.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) and it's quite simple to use:

```
Using Xlfile As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Using XLBook As HSSFWorkbook = New HSSFWorkbook(Xlfile)
        Using XLSheet As NPOI.SS.UserModel.Sheet = XLBook.GetSheetAt(0)

            Dim CurrentRow As NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFRow
                        Dim CurrentCell As NPOI.SS.UserModel.Cell
                        Dim RowEnum As IEnumerator = XLSheet.GetRowEnumerator()

            While RowEnum.MoveNext
                          If (RowEnum.Current IsNot Nothing) Then
                              CurrentRow = TryCast(RowEnum.Current, NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFRow)
                    Select Case CurrentCell.CellType
                        Case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.STRING
                            ' CurrentCell.StringCellValue
                        Case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.NUMERIC
                            ' CurrentCell.NumericCellValue.ToString()
                    End Select
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    Xlfile.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: I was looking at and found something called "Excel package" http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/ do you know if they still develop this?

Comment: @chobo2: Yes, I had tried that one a couple of years ago but then I've given up cause it seems that the project has been abandoned. I would suggest you to try NPOI cause it's really simple and it works. I reads and writes all excel versions.

Comment: @LeftyX: Is there is any way in NPOI to get all charts in excel sheet.

Comment: @PankajAgarwal: I am afraid I can't help. Have never done anything like that. I would suggest you to open a new question, anyway.