# reading excel worksheet in mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could someone help with some good examples of on how to read a excel spreadsheet in .Net 4.0 using MVC?

I will have to read 3-4 worksheets in an Excel spreadsheet, loop through the rows in each worksheet retrieve the values in each cell and then store it in the database. Looking for some code with examples to point me in the right directions.

Thanks for your help in Advance.
Sue.

Comment: Maybe searching through previous questions will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062092/upload-excel-file-and-extract-data-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you for providing the link. I had searched but could not find exactly what I was looking for and hence posted the question. Thank you again.

Comment: so did the link help? Was it the one you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks....I just needed a starting point...have you heard of EPP to do the same function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). 
There you have so many examples, you can try to use example ImportXlsToDataTable